# How do I get yesterday date in Freeswitch?

Tags: date, freeswitch, dialplan

In Freeswitch dialplan, I know I can get today date using ${strftime(%Y%m%d}, but how do I get yesterday date correctly?
I can do ${strftime(%Y%m)}${expr(${strftime(%d}-1)}, but what about yesterday date of Jan, 1st, 2017?
Thanks for all your helps.

Answer (score 0):

**var.xml**

```
<X-PRE-PROCESS cmd="exec-set" data="yesterday=date -d 'yesterday' +'%b %d %Y'">
```

**fs_cli**

```
freeswitch@host> eval $${yesterday}
Nov 16 2017
```